# Run python program in PyCharm with command line in console

Tags: python, terminal, console, pycharm

I have a python file named "python_file.py" and I want to run it with a command line such as "python python_file.py" by typing it in the terminal, and not in the python console. I succeed one time, but when I change my working directory, it no longer works.

When I tried, it displays something like "python isn't known as a intern program, a runnable program or a command file".

And I'm using Python 3.7.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I think there is one. Is it the venv directory ? Actually I restart PyCharm and I don"t know how but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a run/debug configuration, as explained in [the official help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html):

1. Click on **the button left of the green arrow symbol** (the green arrow might be greyed out, but that's fine):

   [image: run/debug configurations]
2. Click on **Edit Configurations**.
3. Click on the `+` symbol

   [image: new configuration]
4. Click on **Python**.
5. On the right side, enter/activate the following:

   - **Name** (a string that describes your according project)
   - **Single instance only** (this is less complicated for you)
6. Click on the **Configuration** tab.
7. Select a type of target from the **Script path/Module name**
8. Enter the path to your Python script in the according box.
9. Select the Python interpreter (Python 3.x will be fine).
10. In the **Execution** section, select either **Emulate terminal in output console** or **Run with Python console**.
11. Apply the changes and close the dialog.
12. Click on **the button left of the green arrow symbol** to run your program from the internal command line.